# recaptcha in php only with no jquery or ajax

Tags: php, ajax, recaptcha

I am having trouble checking if recaptcha is checked or not in authController.php.  In the signup.php page, when user submits the form, form method is post, and action = authController.php

My signup page works perfectly fine without recaptcha.  Assuming I define recaptcha div correctly along with the valid secretkey on signup.php so that I don't have to put irreleant stuff here, My ONLY question is how do I check recaptha POST in authController.php.  What's happening right now is that if I check or don't check recaptcha, when the form is submitted, it comes back saying recaptcha is required.  If I commnent the code out, then obviously registration works.

After the signup form is submitted, I am coming back to the signup form EVEN when successful and change the REGISTER button to EMAIL SENT in green color, and disable button itself.  Having said that, I think what is happening is that when the page gets reloaded, it loses track of checkmark since I am using PHP.  How I know that is after submitting, checked is not checked anymore, but I think there has to be a way to use PURE php.  Also then howcome First Name, Last name ... are all recognized after submitting.  Kind of getting frustated now with this.  Here is how I am checking if recaptcha was checked or not in authController.php file.

```
    '''
    if(empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
    {
      $errors[captcha_error'] = "Captcha is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $secretKey = "mykey";
        $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secretKey.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        $response = file_get_contents($url);
        $response_data = json_decode($response);
        
        if($response_data->success)
            $errors['captcha_error'] = null;
    }
    '''
```

errors is array defined above, the syntax is correct.  On the signup.php page, I check if errors array captcha_error is SET or NULL. This is how I know if the box was checked or not.  If I HAVE to use ajax using $data and success, then how please.  Please remember I using PURE php and no jquery OR AJAX  (although I think I may end up using it since ajax won't reload whole page, and therefore I WONT lose the checkmark, and may be that is my problem), but PHP is preferred.  Thanks

Comment: Something needs to happen in javascript to add g-recaptcha-response to the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting my hosting just about when I was decided to give up, the conclusion was that the "allow_url_fopen" was not checked off in my php settings.  So it wasn't my code. It worked like charm after the option was checked.  Not sure why it was unchecked by default in the first place, and no youtube video shows to make sure of this.

Sigh....

Hopefully, it helps other people who are struggling in same situation

Answer (score 0):

I made a very simple signup page called experiment.php with minimal content, and its still not working. I still getting echoed FAILURE.  I have watched youtube videos on how to use recaptcha with PHP.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled recaptcha about 9 times now thinking may be I had something wrong with the settings. Using recaptcha v2 by the way. Finally I searched google, and I ended up using their DEMO keys and will display a warning (which is normal since they are for experiment only), and still not working. If any of you can use my code below and make it work, I will appreciate please. You are more than welcome to change the keys to your keys and see if it works for you at your end. Currently google demo keys are used below.  The 3 pictures to click will popup, it shows green chekmark, but after submit, it says FAILURE.

I just want to see IF my keys are wrong OR something wrong with my coding???

By the way, it also says on my recaptcha site:  We detected that your site is not verifying reCAPTCHA solutions. This is required for the proper use of reCAPTCHA on your site. Please see our developer site for more information.  I googled but no use, if this message means my settings are wrong, then please hint me.

If my coding is wrong, then understood, OTHERWISE I really wonder how they became 136 billion dollar industry.  Very Very frustrated with this recaptcha business.

Here is the link to the video I followed:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyOu0b6R3m0

```
    '''
       <?php 
         if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
         {
             $e = $_POST['myemail'];
             $secretKey = '66LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe';
             $responseKey = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
             $url='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretKey&response=$responseKey';
             $response = file_get_contents($url); 
             $response = json_decode($response);
        if($response->success)
              echo "success";
        else
              echo "failure";
       }
       ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
       <style>
  .success {
      background-color: lightseagreen;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 20px;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px 32px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 22px;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 100%;
 }

.register {
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 2px solid lightseagreen;
  color: green;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 22px;
   margin: 4px 2px;
   cursor: pointer;
   width: 100%;
  }

</style>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title> Registration </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="container" style = "transform:scale(.8);">
 <div class="title">Registration</div><br>
 <div>
  <form action="experiment.php" method = "post">

    <div class="user-details">
      <div class="input-box">
        <span class="details">Email</span>
        <input type="email" name = "myemail" required>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data- 
    sitekey="6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
  </div>
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"async defer></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

'''